# Im trying to create a button for my react native assignment but i keep getting an unexpected token, syntax error

Tags: react-native

I am a newbie to react-native and Im trying to create a button for my react native assignment but i keep getting an unexpected token, syntax error. Here is the code below (They say the error is in lines 6 - 11)

I am using  https://snack.expo.io/  to test out my code

Here is the exact words it says about the error below:

'''
    /module:/App.js: Unexpected token (8:18)

6 - const Todo = props => (

7 -  View>

8 -    title="delete" />

9 -   {props.todo.text}

10 - /View>

11 - )

Evaluating module://App.js.js

Loading module://App.js
'''

For some reason on stack overflow its not showing (View, Button, Text, ScrollView), but they are there, but you can add them back as needed for the code to work properly.

I have looked over the code but I cant seem to get what I am missing, I will add the entire code under this so you can see all the code I am working with.

Thanks for the help!

```
import React from 'react'; 
import {View, Button, Text, ScrollView} from 'react-native'

let id = 0

const Todo = props => (
<View>
  <Button><onPress={props.onDelete}> title="delete" />
  <Text>{props.todo.text}</Text>
</View>
)

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      todos: [],
    }
  }
}

addTodo() {
  id++
  const text = 'TODO number ${id}'
  this.setState({
    todos: [
      ...this.state.todos,
{id: id, text: text, checked: false},
    ],
  })
}

removeTodo(id) {
  this.setState({
    todo: this.state.todo.filter(todo => todo.id !
    )
  })
}

toggleTodo(id) {
  this.setState({
    todos: this.site.todo.map(todo => {
if (todo.id !== id) return todo 
return {
  id: todo.id
  text: todo.text
  checked: !todo.checked
      }
    })
  })
}

render() {
  return(
    <View>
      <Text>Todo count: this.state.todo.length}
        </Text>
        <Text>Unchecked todo count: this.state.todos.filter(todo => !todo.checked).length}    </Text>
        <Button onPress={() => this.addToDo()} title ="Add TODO" />
        <ScrollView>
        {this.state.todo.map(todo => (
          <Todo
          onToggle={() => this.toggleTodo(todo.id)}
          onDelete={() => this.removeTodo(todo.id)}
          todo={todo}
          />
        ))}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
  )
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the Todo function as below

```
 const Todo = props => (
    <View>
     <Button onPress={props.onDelete} title="delete" />
     <Text>{props.todo.text}</Text>
    </View>
 )
```

But even after this your code won't compile. there are lot of compilation issues in your code. please check and try again.

Answer (score 0):

But I already have those at the top of the code

```
import React from 'react'; 
import {View, Button, Text, ScrollView} from 'react-native'
```

unless thats not the right way to import for buttons? So I am definetly missing something.

So Ill try the

```
import Button from 'react-native';
```

And see what happens

thanks for the help